# switch specific elements between two arrays and have the switched element placed at end of the first array

Tags: c++

i'm trying to make it so if i enter the number 3 , the matrix would change to {1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,0}, i'm not sure if the method of switching the element between two arrays is the best way to do it and i'm trying to do it using pointers

```
using namespace std;
#include <iomanip>
int main() {

    int arr[3][4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 }, i, j,c;
    int* ptr = &arr[0][0];

    int zero[3][4] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };
    int* zptr = &zero [0][0];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(8) << arr[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << ' ' << endl;
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (arr[i][0] = i)
        {
            break;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
            cin >> i;
             cout << ptr;
    }
    
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `arr[i][0] = i` this is an assignment, not a comparison. You might have meant `arr[i][0] == i` ; note two equal signs. However, the condition `arr[i][0] == i` doesn't actually hold for any `i`. It's unclear what this code is trying to achieve. E.g. `cin >> i` doesn't make any sense - why are you taking user input and storing it in the loop index?

Answer (score 0):

you could use easier approach to achieve this using vector in c++ and by finding the index of the input element, consider this example :

```
int getIndex(vector<int> v, int K) {
    auto it = find(v.begin(), v.end(), K);

    // calculating the index of K
    // note that here i'm supposed the input is valid
    int index = it - v.begin();
    return index;
}
```

and you can use the index you get to 1) append in A the element B[index], 2) assign B[index] to A[index] and 3) erase the element A[index].

hope this can be helpful.